# Powershell foreach in batches of 10

Tags: powershell, for-loop, foreach

I have following code to get data from partner center

```
$custIDs = Get-MicrosoftPartner
foreach ($custID in $custIDs)

{
 Export-MicrosoftData -CustomerId $custID
 }
```

In this `foreach` loop i have thousand of `CustomerID` so i want to run this command in step of 10, in first iteration grab first 10 Customers, in next 10 and so on.

I have code which works what i want but its much slower than when loop through all the customers at once, (And that job is slow too )

```
$custIDs = Get-MicrosoftPartner


$group = 10 # step of 10
$i = 0


do {
     $custIDs[$i..(($i+= $group) - 1)]
     '*****'

     Export-MicrosoftData -CustomerId $custIDs

     }
      until ($i -ge $custIDs.count -1)




function Export-MicrosoftData {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        # Customer ID from Microsoft Partner Center
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)][string[]]$CustomerId
    )


        $CustomerId.ForEach({
            $Organization = [myClass]::new()
            $Organization.PopulateData($_)
            $ArrayOfOrganizations.Add($Organization)
        })
```

Is there any more efficient way of doing this ?

Comment: If looping through all items at once is confirmed to be faster than doing it in batches of 10, then... it looks like there *is* a more efficient way of doing this than batches of 10?

Comment: Also, what is `Get-MicrosoftPartnerCustomers`? I can't seem to find any documentation on this, so I assume that's something you wrote?

Comment: I need to go in steps because i'm running it in test environment currently, in production i'll have thousand of records.Get-MicrosoftPartnerCustomers is my custom function for getting Subscriptoins

Comment: It's best when you show that as well, because without seeing what it does it's impossible to say if it could be faster. Other than that, it's still unclear to me how "batches of 10" is supposed to help when you want to go through all of them anyway.

Comment: Just posted, thanks, i need to process them "X at a time", for example, 10, that's requirement

Comment: I get that it's a requirement. I'd like to *understand* it. I'm asking for the third time now: When looping through all IDs is faster than doing batches of 10, and you will loop through all IDs *anyway*, then why bother doing batches of 10? Apparently it has only drawbacks and no advantage.

Comment: Anyway, i'm using this opportunity to learn how to do it, bear in mind that looping through all IDs is terrible slow too, so i'm curious is there any way to speed this up

Comment: The loop is not the slow thing here. Powershell can loop though ten thousands of things in a split second. Making batches of ten only increases the overhead, it will not speed up the loop.

Comment: Don't call `Export-Csv` inside `foreach` - pipe all the output to it

Comment: @xerks - You said that your code for "batch of 10" works. Is it faster than doing them all at one time? By what percent is it faster? Metrics.

Comment: No, it's slower

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[$i..(($i+= $group) - 1)]` is wrong. This sets the starting `$i` too low for every batch except the first one, which means you're doing excessively more work than necessary.

You mean `[($i * $group)..(($i+1) * $group - 1)]`, i.e. something like this

```
$batches = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $custIDs.Count / $group; $i++) {
    ,$custIDs[($i * $group)..(($i+1) * $group - 1)]
}
```

Note the `,` at the start, which makes sure that you get a nested array.

---

That being said, I would restructure the `Export-MicrosoftOrganizationData`. Primarily because *retrieving* the objects and *exporting* them are two different things and they should not be done in the same function.

This makes everything simpler - `begin` and `end` blocks are not needed anymore, there is no need for an intermediate array and the function (let's call it `Get-MicrosoftOrganizationData`) becomes more versatile overall:

```
function Get-MicrosoftOrganizationData {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)] # CustomerId from Microsoft Partner Center
        [string[]]$CustomerId
    )
    @($CustomerId) | ForEach-Object {
        $Organization = [Organization]::new()
        $Organization.PopulateMicrosoftData($_)
        $Organization
    }
}
```

The `Export-Csv` call is not complicated enough to be tucked into the function anyway:

```
$custIDs = Get-MicrosoftPartnerCustomers
$orgData = $custIDs | Get-MicrosoftOrganizationData
$orgData | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "," -Path .\TestOutputOrg.csv
```

Essentially you could even put all of that onto one line.

Overall, making batches of X out of the input might be useful for testing things, but if you're going to process *all* IDs anyway, it's not a useful strategy.